# How to handle the throttling of AWS Lambda func for an API call w rate lmit of 200?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs, rate-limiting

My situation is as follows:

- An API call with a rate limit of 200 per min.
- From this API msg is pushed to SQS.
- Have to trigger a Lambda func using SQS queue to get the results from the API.

But the problem is that the Lambda func is throttling and giving 429 response code in between if the request is more than 200 in a min.

Tried so many thing, but didn't work out! Configured SQS queue wait time, use cloudwatch events and so on.

Comment: Can you share the SQS lambda trigger config? How is your lambda configured in term of memory and timeout? How long does it take for your lambda to process 1 event? Have you looked at this post for limiting the number of lambda that can run in parallel from SQS trigger: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/ ?

Comment: I have an SQS queue from which the lambda is triggered, visibility timeout is 30 seconds, the msg wait time is below 20 seconds limit & lambda processes 200 API calls in 5-6 seconds.